# Json web token does not expire

Tags: node.js, jwt, express-jwt

I just implemented a json web token authentication, on my backend I send the token which is created by `jsonwebtoken` to the client as following:

```
var token = jwt.sign(user, secret.secretToken, { expiresInMinutes: 1 });
return res.json({ token: token });
```

and on the client side I simply store this token to the SessionStorage. The thing is that the token does not expire after a minute, am I missing something?

**EDIT:** I implemented same thing which is shown in [this](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/) post.

Answer (score 22):

I found myself having the same problem when not providing an object as the first argument to `jwt.sign`, e.g. `jwt.sign('testuser', secret.secretToken, { expiresIn: '1h' });`.

This wrong usage of `jwt.sign` does work even though it is wrong, it just ignores the provided settings. https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/64

Be sure to provide an object as first argument, like `jwt.sign({user: 'testuser'}, secret.secretToken, { expiresIn: '1h' });`

**Update:**
There have been reported problems with usage of non standard javascript objects, such as from mongoose. Version 5.5.2 has a fix for this. More details [here](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/147). Thanks @gugol for the notice. Make sure you pass a plain object with the properties you need, not a direct database object or similar.

Comment: Wow. This was driving me nuts. Thanks Marius.

Comment: I am passing it an object and still the token does not expire. I am using `expiresIn:60` because "expiresInMinutes" is deprecated now.

Comment: @gugol You should open a new issue on github or create a new question here then, with your complete usage example.

Comment: @MariusRumpf I did but I got no answer yet: https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/147

Answer (score 4):

The token will not *automatically* be deleted from the Session storage.  However, if you try to verify that the token is valid, the expired token should be invalid.

From [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-json-web-tokens-node-js/), the validity check should throw an exception:

```
if (token) {
  try {
    var decoded = jwt.decode(token, app.get('jwtTokenSecret'));

    // handle token here

  } catch (err) {
    return next();
  }
} else {
  next();
}
```

Verify is also included in the [jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) package.  And this is from the docs:

> (Synchronous with callback) Returns the payload decoded if the
>   signature (and optionally **expiration**, audience, issuer) are valid. If
>   not, it will return the error.

Comment: Hey Davin, thanks for the answer. The problem was in their source code, as you see the time is multiplied with 1000 before, and they fixed it 10 days ago https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/commit/44ed992ee58a90db3fc4a05d08cdf8356ba515c1

Comment: jwt.verify method should be used rather than jwt.decode method.

Answer (score 0):

```
//use this to create the token

  var token = jwt.sign({
  exp: "1h",
  data: "payload"
   }, "secret");

/*while checking the token ,Throws error if the token is expired else you will get the decoded data*/

jwt.verify(token, 'secret', function(err, decoded) {
  if (err) {
    /*
      err = {
        name: 'TokenExpiredError',
        message: 'jwt expired',
        expiredAt: 1408621000
      }
    */
  }
});
```